# tf.train.SequenceExample with lists at each step

Tags: python, tensorflow

How is a list of values passed into a feature_list?  The documentation suggests that this is valid but it is not clear how this is accomplished given that passing a list result in an error.

```
>>> tf.train.SequenceExample().feature_lists.feature_list["multiple"].feature.add().int64_list.value.append([1,2,3,4])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/internal    /containers.py", line 251, in append
    self._values.append(self._type_checker.CheckValue(value))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/internal    /type_checkers.py", line 132, in CheckValue
raise TypeError(message)
TypeError: [1, 2, 3, 4] has type <type 'list'>, but expected one of: (<type 'int'>, <type 'long'>)
```

This is an example given in the example proto file.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/example/example.proto

```
// Conditionally conformant FeatureLists, the parser configuration determines
// if the feature sizes must match:
//    feature_lists: { feature_list: {
//      key: "movie_ratings"
//      value: { feature: { float_list: { value: [ 4.5 ] } }
//               feature: { float_list: { value: [ 5.0, 6.0 ] } } }
//    } }
```

Is it necessary to use something other than append when adding a list?

An example of a sequence would be...

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7],[8,9,10]]
```

...where there are four steps in this sequence, and at each step there is a set of values.  The desired result would look something like the example below.

```
    feature_lists: { feature_list: {
      key: "movie_ratings"
      value: { feature: { float_list: { value: [ 1, 2, 3 ] } }
               feature: { float_list: { value: [ 4, 5 ] } }
               feature: { float_list: { value: [ 6, 7 ] } }
               feature: { float_list: { value: [ 8, 9, 10 ] } } }
    } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use extend instead of append.

```
tf.train.SequenceExample().feature_lists.feature_list["multiple"].feature.add().int64_list.value.extend([1,2,3,4])
```